# How to delete a SQL database table in R

Tags: mysql, sql, r

I created a table using dbWriteTable in R (and then appended more data to it), using two commands:

```
dbWriteTable(my_db, name="dallas_flights", value=nov_trim, overwrite = TRUE, row.names = FALSE)
dbWriteTable(my_db, name="dallas_flights", value=dec_trim, append = TRUE, row.names = FALSE)
```

After I ran my script, I deleted everything using rm(list=ls()). When I type, ls() into R, I get character(0).

However, when I try to rerun the script, and reach these two commands, I get an error indicating that the table still exists:

```
Error in sqliteExecStatement(con, statement, bind.data) :
```

RS-DBI driver: (error in statement: table dallas_flights already exists)

I do not know how to delete this table. Any advice?

Comment: The database and R are two separate things. The table exists in the database, not in R. Your R workspace has absolutely no connection to the presence or absence of tables in your database. To drop a table, you need to send a `DROP TABLE` query to the database.

Comment: Try `dbRemoveTable(my_db, "dallas_flights")` .

Answer (score 1):

For clarification because there is still no answer even if there is a good answer in comment of G. Grothendieck

```
DBI::dbRemoveTable(conn, name = "table_name")
```